# Are women obligated in neilah

Tags: halacha, women, yom-kippur, orach-chaim, neilah

According to Halacha, are women obligated to recite neilah on Yom Kippur? Or are they exempt because it is a positive time bound commandment?

Comment: It's a [question](https://olamot.net/shiurim/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91-%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%A4-%D7%95%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A4-2/) if they even can.

Comment: No rishon ever said they were exempt, and they all knew women